# Is it possible to export multiple datatables at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to export multiple datatables in single page and have one export button for all the tables on the page?

Any link for suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to get all table's objects and trigger export function on all of them. Example code below:

```
function exportAllDatatables() {

    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    var table2 = $('#myTable2').DataTable();

    //Trigger the button at index 2-1 (Wherever your export button in each table):
    table.button( '2-1' ).trigger();
    table2.button( '2-1' ).trigger();
}
```

Reference to trigger function of export button here:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/button%28%29.trigger%28%29

Comment: if you can provide a fiddle it would be great

Comment: how to merge that two table ? and how can i show those data in PDF ?

Comment: Please do some research, try some code yourself, add some code to the question, and update your question as to what exactly is not working and what did you try. I gave you code sample of `trigger` function which is useful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible even with buttons collection.
Here is advance demo https://jsfiddle.net/4kpvba23/4/ (can export csv, excel, pdf of two or more than tables simultaneously )

As pointed out by Kavish Mittai you can trigger single button or multiple button also in collection.

**Button API** (https://datatables.net/reference/api/button())

**Buttons API** (https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons())

**Buttons Trigger API** (https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons().trigger())

> Note: Remember clicking on export all will prompt "Allow multiple download?"
>   in browser to avoid harmful downloading and it's depend on user
>   interaction you can't disable it.

#### Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var settings = {
        "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-3 col-left'l><'col-xs-6 col-right'B><'col-xs-3 col-right'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-3 col-left'i><'col-xs-9 col-right'p>>",
        "buttons": [
            'colvis',
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Select',
                buttons: [
                    'selectAll',
                    'selectNone'
                ]
            },
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Copy',
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: 'Copy Selected',
                    exportOptions: {
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    text: 'Copy Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: false,
                            page: 'current',
                            search: 'applied'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'CSV',
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    text: 'Export to CSV Selected Rows',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    text: 'Export to CSV Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: false,
                            page: 'current',
                            search: 'applied'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Excel',
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: 'Export to Excel Selected Rows',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: 'Export to Excel Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: false,
                            page: 'current',
                            search: 'applied'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'PDF',
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    text: 'Export to PDF Selected Rows',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                }, {

                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    text: 'Export to PDF Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: true,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: false,
                            page: 'current',
                            search: 'applied'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Print',
                buttons: [{
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'Print Selected Rows',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: false,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: true
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'Print Current Page',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible',
                        stripHtml: false,
                        modifier: {
                            selected: false,
                            page: 'current',
                            search: 'applied'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    };

    var table = $('#example').DataTable(settings);
    var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable(settings);

    $(document).on('click', '#exportAll', function() {

        /*
         * For Table 1
         * ===========
         */

        //Index of "csv" button is 3 and in it "export to csv current  page" is at index 1 so it'll be 3-1
        //Index of "excel" button is 4 and in it "export to excel current  page" is at index 1 so it'll be 4-1
        //Index of "pdf" button is 5 and in it "export to pdf current  page" is at index 1 so it'll be 5-1
        table.buttons(['3-1', '4-1', '5-1']).trigger();

        /*
         * For Table 2
         * ===========
         */

        //Index of "csv" button is 3 and in it "export to csv current  page" is at index 1 so it'll be 3-1
        //Index of "excel" button is 4 and in it "export to excel current  page" is at index 1 so it'll be 4-1
        //Index of "pdf" button is 5 and in it "export to pdf current  page" is at index 1 so it'll be 5-1
        table2.buttons(['3-1', '4-1', '5-1']).trigger();
    });
});
```

```css
#example_wrapper{
 margin-bottom: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.5.0/b-colvis-1.5.0/b-flash-1.5.0/b-html5-1.5.0/b-print-1.5.0/cr-1.4.1/fc-3.2.4/fh-3.1.3/kt-2.3.2/r-2.2.1/rg-1.0.2/rr-1.2.3/sc-1.4.3/sl-1.2.4/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
/>

<button id="exportAll">Export All</button>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/af-2.2.2/b-1.5.0/b-colvis-1.5.0/b-flash-1.5.0/b-html5-1.5.0/b-print-1.5.0/cr-1.4.1/fc-3.2.4/fh-3.1.3/kt-2.3.2/r-2.2.1/rg-1.0.2/rr-1.2.3/sc-1.4.3/sl-1.2.4/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes its true for multiple datatable and multiple PDF,Csv etc but i need all the table in one PDF means Two or more datatable export in single PDF file. is that possible ?